# File Management with Mutiple External USB Drives and NAS

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-management

I have 1 NAS, with 2TB of Storage, 4 External USB HDD Drives from 250Gb to 1TB, a lot of USB Flash Drives. They all have some duplication of files as I have copy them from one to another to safe keep. Now with a lot of these it is getting out of hand.

I want to upload them all to the Cloud. Especially after I seen some of my picture and video getting bit rot.

Is there any simply solution i can compared all of these files for duplication, remove them, and categories them before I upload them to Cloud WITHOUT saving them into one places. ( Otherwise i will need to buy a 8TB HDD first )Or are there any Cloud solution that all me to upload them first and do the file management online.

And the finding images or video or file that have similar names, so i could easily compare them to see if they are corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I used Wincatalog a while ago for the same issue.
http://www.wincatalog.com/file-indexing.html

If you only need it once before uploading then the 30day-trial will be enough.